# Lightning Components: why force:inputField picklist select renders disabled?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I originally came across this issue when reviewing the response to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580). There is also a similar [question for lookup inputs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96990).

The force:inputField component is really useful for making an input form based on sObject type. However, when using a picklist or multipicklist field type it renders as disabled by default.

Here is a sample component that demonstrates this.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

  <aura:attribute name="task" type="Task" default="{ sobjectType: 'Task' }"/>

  <force:inputField value="{!v.task.Priority}" />

</aura:component>
```

One hack I found to enable it again is to remove the disabled attribute in the renderer.

```
render : function(cmp, helper) {
    var element = this.superRender();
    element[0].children[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
    return element;
}
```

You could also leverage jQuery as shown [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/96909/25732).

Is there a better way to enable this input?

Answer (score 5):

I'm in contact with premier support from salesforce. On the phone they confirmed it as a bug and told me about a fix scheduled for Spring'16 (safeharbor).

In the meantime they encouraged me using one of the mentioned workarounds.

It would be very helpful if we had a public list of things which aren't fully functional and known bugs. In this case (and others) I was digging days in the dark, figured workarounds and burned also time of the support.

Comment: Did you ever get a link to this Bug/Known Issue? It doesn't appear to be fixed and workarounds cannot always be applied. I'm finding that the disabled Select isn't being output into the DOM as a Select. Instead, it is being output as a link, styled to look like a disabled select. Therefore, there is nothing usable to be re-enabled.

Comment: Here's link to known issue, https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BaTQAU

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue tentatively scheduled to be fixed in Spring '17 release

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BaTQAU

Comment: Unbelievable - one full year later and the bug is still there. And from the outside it looks like a small glitch in the rendering and very easy to fix. Feels like force:inputField is not the highest prioritized thing on the roadmap.